# iOS Development - Provisioning Profile with no device

Tags: ios, xcode

I have developed an Ionic App (hybrid for iOS & Android). I have Xcode 8.3.3 and have purchased a year's subscription to the Apple Developer Program.

I would not like to test and deploy my app to Apple's App Store. In order to do so, I need first create a **Provisioning Profile**.

In the [Developer Console](http://developer.apple.com), I got to:

Provisioning Profiles -> Development -> iOS App Development -> Select App ID -> Select certificates -> Select devices -> create devise.

It then asks me for my devise `Name` and `UDID`. I do not have any Apple devises. I Do have a MacBookPro I use for development though.  I then figure I should not try:

Provisioning Profiles -> Development

But rather:

Provisioning Profiles -> Distribution

As I will need to deploy this to the App Store.

Provisioning Profiles -> Distribution -> + -> App Store -> Select App ID -> Select certificates

I then follow the instructions to create a certificate. The newly created certificate is visible under "Certificates".

However, if I go back to "Provisioning Profiles", there are no profiles.

**Question**

Why can't I create a Provisioning Profile?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Main purpose of the `Development` provisioning profile is to test our app on iOS devices, which is under development**, Because iOS devices will install the app from Appstore & authorised developer account.

If you are not added any devices into your account then there is no point creating development provisioning profile. Because you can not use that certificate to install on any other devices. For simulator no need any certificate.

Apple document says : [Before creating a development provisioning profile, verify that you have an App ID, one or more development certificates, and one or more devices.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingProfiles/MaintainingProfiles.html)

Comment: Thank you for the info. Does that mean I can still distribute the app to the App Store?

Comment: For App Store distribution no need devices. But you have to create App Store distribution certificate.