# iOS how to add a provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, xcode8, itunes

I am using `Xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)`. I have an app developed that I would like to deploy to Apple's App Store.

In order to Archive and deploy, I understand I first need a provisioning profile. So, in the developer console, I set up an **iOS Distribution Provisioning Profile**.

[image]

I also have the following certificates:

[image]

On my MacBook, I added the following certificates to the key chain:

[image][image]

Then when I go to Xcode, I would expect to have a Provisioning Profile:

[image]

But as you can see, it `Failed to create provisioning profile` and `No profiles for 'com.ionicframework.thewhozoo912107' were found`.

I am obviously missing some step in order to create the Provisioning Profile in order to distribute the app to the Apple App Store.

**Question**

If anyone can suggest what I need to do in order to create a working provisioning profile in order to distribute the app, I would appreciate the help.

**More info:**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to create provisioning profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39603667/failed-to-create-provisioning-profile)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Solution:**

I fixed this in Xcode by unchecking `Automatically Manage Signing`, and then selecting my provisioning profile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem as well when I was developing my first app. It took a while, since I managed it. Try to plug your iOS device in your computer and then it should work.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for the advise. Unfortunately I don't have an Apple devise to plug in. I also cannot plug in a friends devise because my MacBookPro has no usb ports (only Thunderbolt 2 ports). I would have expected to be able to deploy an app to the App Store without having to purchase an Apple device too. From the following, I understand that this should be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653590/ios-development-provisioning-profile-with-no-devise/44653899?noredirect=1#comment76293126_44653899